# DNSSEC chain of trust

Tags: domain-name-system, dnssec

My test environment details are as follows :-

> ```
> I have fake-root server "172.16.93.193"
> DNS resolver "172.16.93.101"
> DNS server "172.16.96.93"
> ```

I have already configured my resolver and it working fine "change named.ca to query my fake-root-server"

I am trying to validate DNSSEC "Chain-Of-Trust" with  the following configuration :-

- Added my record of NS at fake root server.

> ```
> test.         IN NS 172.16.96.93
> test.         IN A  172.16.96.93
> test.         IN DS 41751 10 1 B582E2C5AB6551FA23B3947CAA39BAC18C51A001
> test.         IN DS 41751 10 2 51A4CCCD5Ff8D328FECD018D9D296B7603FB7B2E3286CE4EFC3A64C0 73D32D55
> ```

- Added my test zone at my dns server.

> ```
> zone "test" {
>         type master;
>         file "Test/Signed/test.zone.signed";
>
> };
> ```

When query my resolver "dig @localhost test" it will replay by :-

```
> ; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1 <<>> @localhost test
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 53882
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;misr.              IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: ::1#53(::1)
;; WHEN: Sat Oct 18 12:27:55 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 22
```

Could you advice how to fix this problem ?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: @Resolver , nothing added to log. What log you want ? root or dns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my fatal mistake :-

@Fake root with mistake :-

```
test.         IN NS 172.16.96.93
test.         IN A  172.16.96.93
```

@Fake Root With Mistake solved :-

```
test.         IN NS ns1.test.
ns1.test.         IN A  172.16.96.93
```

All is working Ok now.